# How the indirect addressing works?

Tags: functional-programming

By other words, can anyone explain how indirect addressing works?

I red MARIE's LoadI X over and over and still didnt understand the logic behind it.

```
LoadI X loads the value which is stored at address of the address X into the AC
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the variable X contain the value 0xABC, assumed to be a valid memory address, and let the address of X be 0xDEF.

Then X denotes the value of what is stored at 0xDEF and *X (indirect addressing) is the value of what is stored at 0xABC (not said here).

---

Without indirect addressing, there would probably be no computers, because only dumb programs could be written.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!